# Tags: Vodafone-858 versus Huawai-u8160

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

I just noticed the [vodafone-858](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vodafone-858) (x1) being created, and a tag wiki for it as well. According to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28763/16575), "Vodafone 858" is just a different name for the Huawai u8160 ([huawai-u8160](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/huawai-u8160), x13).

Can somebody confirm this? If so, I'd suggest to merge the two, and make the vodafone tag a synonym to the manufacturers tag.

**EDIT:** Here's [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26161/16575) confirming both devices being identical, "Vodafone 858" just being a branded "Huawai u8160".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. Merged and synonym created.